Excel instance very slow when returning data from redshift database
I don't have many details for this since I can't reproduce it on my side, so here goes.
We have an Excel that that displays data returned from a redshift data. For the purposes of the question, I simply created a new Excel file (xlsx), went to "Data" -> "Get Data" -> "From other sources" -> "From ODBC". It's a regular xlsx file where the connection is done via power query. There are not macros or VBA code in this new xlsx.
With one particular end-user on the same network, the query downloads about 83 rows every 2-3 seconds. With everyone else (myself included), it downloads about 5,000 rows every 2 seconds, and all 20,000 rows in about 12 seconds.
The end-user has super-fast download speed (faster than mine) so that's not an issue.
We all download the Excel from the same place, so we all have the same Excel.
The weird thing is that he's not having these issues with Excel files connected to sql server. It's only with redshift.
Also, if he runs the query directly in sqlworkbench/j, the data's returned in seconds.
What else can I check?


Can you share the VBA code with us? Because you're not using ODBC, it seems that's going to be a key piece of information.

I updated my question to remove any VBA or macros. It's a simple xlsx that connects to a redshift table and downloads data.
